# React push to view after successful purchase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I've created a react app where a logged-in user can upgrade their account using Stripe.

I'm using the following tutorial to implement Stripe/Express: https://hackernoon.com/stripe-api-reactjs-and-express-bc446bf08301

#### stripeBtn.js

```
axios
      .post("http://localhost:9000/payment", body)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Payment Success");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Payment Error: ", error);
        alert("Payment Error");
      });
  };
```

Testing the Stripe purchase in the React app works because I get `POST /payment 200 737.717 ms - 2261` with my Express back end & can see the test payment data in the Stripe dashboard.

Now I want to push to a new view after the purchase is successful, so I tried using the `.push` method after purchase:

```
axios
      .post("http://localhost:9000/payment", body)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        // alert("Payment Success");
        props.history.push('/prowelcome')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Payment Error: ", error);
        alert("Payment Error");
      });
  };
```

However, adding that line now results in displaying  `alert("Payment Error");` , however the payment is posting successfully to the backend.

I've also tried `this.props.history.push` (which works other places in my app), but those working instances are in my main  App.JS file where I have set state & routes for the app.

I thought of bringing this .js function into App.js, however, the code in the tutorial where this axios/stripe post is included is not a class or functional component (I am a relative n00b to react), so I am sure how I would refactor this to work in app JS or how to fix the `.push` method.

### stripeBtn.js (full code)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import axios from "axios";

const stripeBtn = (props) => {
  const publishableKey = process.env.STRIPE_PK;
  const onToken = token => {
    const body = {
      amount: 9600,
      token: token
    }; axios
      .post("http://localhost:9000/payment", body)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        // alert("Payment Success");
        this.props.history.push('/prowelcome')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Payment Error: ", error);
        alert("Payment Error");
      });
  };
  return (
    <StripeCheckout
      label="Go Premium" //Component button text
      name="Business LLC" //Modal Header
      description="Upgrade to a premium account today."
      panelLabel="Go Premium" //Submit button in modal
      amount={9600}
      token={onToken}
      stripeKey={publishableKey}
      billingAddress={false}
    />
  );
}
export default stripeBtn;
```

Comment: I think you can use hooks to do this or convert the functional component to a class and create a state to set a flag, whose value will be changed based on the payment status and when the state changes the render function will be called where you can put a check and use the Redirect component or even history.push

Comment: Can you show us the whole component? To have history in props, you either have to wrap the component with withRouter(Comp) or use the hook: const history = useHistory(); in the component.

Comment: @Domino987 Please see my edit for the full code for ```stripeBtn.js```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the router to the component to have it passed in the props:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
export default withRouter(stripeBtn);
```

This will add the history, location and match props to this component.
After that, you can call `this.props.history.push('/prowelcome')`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this fixed the issue & I learned something new. ```withRouter``` is what I also have in my app.js file where all my routes are so I thought that it wouldn't need to be declared again.